# how to flatten nested nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, underscore.js, lodash

I am building a input application for subdivision data. each subdivision can have 1 to n of sections. my goal is to dynamically populate the ui with the needed inputs, textboxes, radios, checkboxes, etc.. I am combining the data from multiple sources into a single array. since this is dynamic i have created services to change the models to unique names. a screen shot of what it looks like right now

[image: current ui]

the issue i need help with is the checkboxes. I cannot access them from the html. here is a example of how i am accessing a nested array. this works fine.

```
 <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in section.sectionBuilderDeveloper">
                <td class="bd-td">{{item.type}}</td>
                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                <td class="radio-td">
                    <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" id="{{item.idStatus1}}" value="{{item.value1}}" ng-model="model[item.status]">
                        <label for="{{item.forStatus1}}"> Y </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" id="{{item.idStatus2}}" value="{{item.value2}}" ng-model="model[item.status]">
                        <label for="{{item.forStatus2}}"> N </label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="radio-td">
                    <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" id="{{item.idPriceList1}}" value="{{item.value1}}" ng-model="model[item.priceList]">
                        <label for="{{item.forPriceList1}}"> Y </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" id="{{item.idPriceList2}}" value="{{item.value2}}" ng-model="model[item.priceList]">
                        <label for="{{item.forPriceList2}}"> N </label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="radio-td">
                    <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" id="{{item.idInvSheet1}}" value="{{item.value1}}" ng-model="model[item.invSheet]">
                        <label for="{{item.forInvSheet1}}"> Y </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" id="{{item.idInvSheet2}}" value="{{item.value2}}" ng-model="model[item.invSheet]">
                        <label for="{{forInvSheet2}}"> N </label>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

I need to do the same thing with the checkboxes. this does not work.

```
 <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="border-top:none" nowrap align="center" ng-repeat="checkbox in section.sectionFutureCheckboxes">
                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                        <input id="{{checkbox.id}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="model[checkbox.model]">
                        <label for="{{checkbox.for}}"><b>{{checkbox.label}}</b></label>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

So the question is how do i do this? so i flatten the array after i create it or do i change the way I create the checkboxes array in the service?

different plunker with html included
[new plunker with html](http://plnkr.co/edit/a9BS78CY3VAeEws2BrqE?p=preview)

```
        <div class="hpanel" ng-repeat="section in formB6VM.sections">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <ul class="list-inline">
                                <li><h5><b>SecID</b></h5><span>{{section.section_name}}</span></li>
                                <li><h5><b>Section Name</b></h5><span>{{section.section_id}}</span></li>
                                <li><h5><b>Active</b></h5><span>{{section.date_active}}</span></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div ng-include="'modules/survey-input/fb6/views/includes/fb6_input_table.html'"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div ng-include="'modules/survey-input/fb6/views/includes/fb6_builder_developer_table.html'"></div>
                        <div ng-include="'modules/survey-input/fb6/views/includes/fb6_future_table.html'"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: `object.checkboxes = object.sectionFutureCheckboxes[0].checkboxes; delete object.sectionFutureCheckboxes[0].checkboxes;` , but Im not sure why you would need this. You can just access them via `object.sectionFutureCheckboxes.checkboxes` where they are now

Comment: In addition to @DelightedD0D 's answer, you should remove the previous checkboxes array with ``delete object.sectionFutureCheckboxes.checkboxes;``

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 yep I was litterally just editing that :)

Comment: @DelightedD0D but it is an array so need `object.sectionFutureCheckboxes[0].checkboxes`

Comment: @charlietfl yup, nice catch I totally missed that

Comment: @texas697 what is higher level problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: i need to need to be able to use those checkboxes in a ng-repeat.

Comment: and why do you need to flatten data to access them?

Comment: ok, let me do the bigger picture in the plunker. i am actually creating that array so im sure there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: ok, i updated plunker. right now i can access everything but the checkboxes.

Comment: ok, completely changed the post. let me know if needs more info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your original question of how to move a nested property of an object to the "root" of the object. The below would have the effect you **were** looking for:

```
object.checkboxes = object.sectionFutureCheckboxes[0].checkboxes; 
delete object.sectionFutureCheckboxes[0].checkboxes;
```

However, as  charlietfl alludes to, there isnt much point to this from an objective point of view, 6 in one hand half a dozen in the other so to speak

After you clarified the issue, what you really need to do is correct the way your HTMl attempts to access the nested object. Specifically, in future_table.html you have:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-condensed">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border-top:none" nowrap align="center" ng-repeat="checkbox in section.sectionFutureCheckboxes">
                        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                            <input id="{{checkbox.id}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="model[checkbox.model]">
                            <label for="{{checkbox.for}}"><b>{{checkbox.label}}</b></label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <h5 class="future-table-h5"><b><i>*** Future Status - **Concept lots are not calculated in total</i></b></h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, `section.sectionFutureCheckboxes` is an **array** so you will need to iterate that first by changing `<tr>` to `<tr ng-repeat="checkboxGroup in section.sectionFutureCheckboxes">` then update `<td ... ng-repeat="checkbox in section.sectionFutureCheckboxes">` to `<td ... ng-repeat="checkbox in checkboxGroup.checkboxes">`

Like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-condensed">
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="checkboxGroup in section.sectionFutureCheckboxes">
                    <td style="border-top:none" nowrap align="center" ng-repeat="checkbox in checkboxGroup.checkboxes">
                        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                            <input id="{{checkbox.id}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="model[checkbox.model]">
                            <label for="{{checkbox.for}}"><b>{{checkbox.label}}</b></label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <h5 class="future-table-h5"><b><i>*** Future Status - **Concept lots are not calculated in total</i></b></h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Here is an [Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7ydqEG6bR825egxzXncY?p=preview)

Now, if you intended for there to only be one row of checkboxes, you'll need to track that back to through the way you create the array and figure out where it getting built incorrectly, but only you will know that.

Comment: can u put in plunker please

Comment: @texas697 I can, but first you'll need to explain what you are actually trying to accomplish. THere is definitely a better way to do it but its hard to give advice when we dont know what your code is supposed to do

Comment: ok, i updated plunker. right now i can access everything but the checkboxes.

Comment: I see the additions in your plunker but there is still no context. What are you trying to achieve? Right now your are just outputting the built JSON into a `pre` tag. The data is there, so the problem is not apparent. I assume you are attempting to build some sort of UI with this data, thats the part we need to know about. What about that doesnt work?

Comment: ok, completely changed the post. let me know if needs more info

Comment: Ok, now I get it, can you add your html to the Plunker and give me the new link?